# Trying to implement color picker in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to implement color picker in uwp using below link

[[1]: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/coding4fun-colorpicker-control-in-uwp-with-xaml-and-c-sharp/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/coding4fun-colorpicker-control-in-uwp-with-xaml-and-c-sharp/)

but while following process and implementing colorchange event it is giving error "unable to add event handler".Any idea would be appreciated

XAML

```
xmlns:my="using:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls" 
  <my:ColorPicker x:Name="W_Paints"
                            Margin="216,203,-6,0" Height="40"
                            Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a color picker with [Coding4Fun](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls/) package by following the  above link and the color picker is successfully created with no error on my side.

I used  version 2.1.8, and also test version 2.1.7 which also worked. My uwp app target version is build 14393, but I also test with target version 10240. So if you created a uwp app with "Coding4Fun Toolkit - Controls" 2.1.7 or 2.1.8 should be able work well. Here is the demo completing code.

XAML Code

```
<Page
x:Class="Coding4fun.MainPage"
...
xmlns:my="using:Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls" >
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tblTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="419,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Code4Fun ColorPicker control Demo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="37" Width="427" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Button x:Name="btnCPopen" Content="Open Color Picker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-5.01,1.529" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Open color Picker for changing Background" Click="btnCPopen_Click" />
    <Border x:Name="BorCP" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="378" Margin="838,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354" />
    <my:ColorPicker x:Name="CPtest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="358" Margin="284,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="374" ColorChanged="CPtest_ColorChanged" Visibility="Collapsed"  />  
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 private void btnCPopen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     CPtest.Visibility = Visibility;
 }
 private void CPtest_ColorChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Color color)
 {
     BorCP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);
 }
```

I also upload the demo [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/Coding4fun) you can download for testing and compare what's wrong with your project.

Comment: Thx i was trying to generate event  through UI property means pafter pressing F4, so it was not working .and how to make color picker  dissappear if background has been changed?